# ERROR 13 (HY000) When Creating Database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I'm trying to create a database and when I type in `CREATE DATABASE epik;` I get the error `ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of './epik' (Errcode: 13)` I am running kubuntu 13.04 with mysql 5.5.31.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Errcode: 13` is a file permission issue.

If your [**datadir**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir) is `/var/lib/mysql`, do the following:

```
cd /var/lib/
ls -l
```

Check the file permissions as make sure `/var/lib/mysql` is owned by `mysql:mysql`.

If it is not, then do this:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

If you ran `sudo`, you are probably root. Make sure root can write into `/var/lib/mysql`

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: To clarify for future folks: I had to use `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`, otherwise I got permission changing rights errors.